# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two matrices `image` & `convolved`. Some of the elements in the convolved must be replace with string "x". The indices corresponding to "x" values are those 1 appears in the image matrix. 
Here are my matrices,

```
import numpy as np

image = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

convolved = np.array([[1., 1., 3., 3., 3.],[1., 1., 3., 3., 3.],[0., 0., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

this is what I have written,

```
for m, i in enumerate(image):
    for n, j in enumerate(i):
        if j == 1:
            #print(n,j)
            convolved[m][n] = "x"
print(convolved)
```

when I run this I get the following error,

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'
```

I would like to have an output of this;

```
array([[1., 'x', 3., 'x', 3.],
       [1., 1., 3., 'x', 'x'],
       [0., 0., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps use `nan` instead of `'x'`

Comment: Why should numbers in a numeric numpy array be replaced by a string? That looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: Well doesn't necessarily be a terrible idea!! In my case "x" represent mines & the rest of the numbers indicate how many mines are there in the surrounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to give the np.array a char value. You are mixing datatypes. That will not work, as np.array expects data of type number.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Either use a unique number instead of 'x', like -1 or change the whole array to be chars, like numpy.chararray.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

image = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

convolved = pd.DataFrame([[1., 1., 3., 3., 3.],[1., 1., 3., 3., 3.],[0., 0., 1., 2., 2.]])

for i in image:
    for j in image[i]:
        if image[i][j] == 1:
            convolved[i][j] = "x"
print(convolved)
```